# Join a string[] Without Using string.Join

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

This question is for academic purposes only.

Let's assume I have the following code ...

```
var split = line.Split(new[] { ',' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var elem = new XElement("shop");
elem.SetAttributeValue("name", split.Take(split.Length - 1));  <=====
elem.SetAttributeValue("tin", split.Last());
```

And I would like the line with the arrow to produce the same result as this ...

```
string.Join(string.Empty, split.Take(split.Length - 1));
```

... without using `string.Join`.

Is that possible? I can't seem to find a LINQ statement to do it ... hopefully y'all already know!

Comment: Interesting answers, but I'm curious, why are you looking for a different approach than string.Join? And also, you say you are looking for a Linq statement, but then your accepted answer (a good one indeed) is not using Linq at all :)

Comment: @Wasp, again the question was academic. Further, I meant __not__ to say I required it be solved via LINQ, but more so that I had been looking for a LINQ statement to do it because I ___thought___ that was the best approach. However, in the end, Guffa showed me a more perfect way.

Comment: So the question _should_ have been - how can I ignore the last segment of this string and strip the commas.  You got lucky and got the answer you _needed_, but not the answer you _asked for_.

Comment: @DStanley, right you are. My apologies friend. Still a very good answer and why I +1'd it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `Split` either, just locate the last comma and use `Substring` to divide the string:

```
int pos = line.LastIndexOf(',');
var elem = new XElement("shop");
elem.SetAttributeValue("name", line.Substring(0, pos).Replace(",", String.Empty));
elem.SetAttributeValue("tin", line.Substring(pos + 1));
```

Comment: Very good answer and the best approach overall. I'm going to edit your answer with my overall solution because a new requirement cropped up and I want people to see it (the `name` field can have commas in it even though they are sending the file via CSV, maybe should have used a better delimiter huh?)

Comment: @Mike: Right, you were joining the strings without commas. You can just remove them from the first string with a `Replace`.

Comment: I was wrong! I didn't have to modify it because there are only two values and you ran the substring to the LAST position every time. Very, very, very good solution and it's extremely efficient as well!

Answer (score 6):

Using a `StringBuilder` for O(n) performance:

```
split
    .Take(split.Length - 1)
    .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, s) => sb.Append(s)).ToString();
```

If the object is to avoid the awkwardness of a tree of combined LINQ calls and static methods, then a straightforward solution is an extension method:

```
public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> self, string separator = "")
{
    return string.Join(separator, self);
}
```

And then:

```
split.Take(split.Length - 1).Join();
```

I find this to read much better than using `string.Join` in complicated expressions.

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
split.Take(split.Length - 1).Aggregate((s1,s2)=> s1 + s2);
```

or the non-linq equivalent:

```
string s = "";
for(int i = 0; i < split.Length - 1; i++)
{
   s += split[i];
}
return s;
```

Comment: +1 … @YoryeNathan, this is a totally acceptable solution. Quadratic runtime, true, but for the probably use-case this might still be *faster* than the solution using the `StringBuilder`: looking at OP’s code this is used to set an XML attribute value called `name` – how long do you expect the collection to be?

Comment: @YoryeNathan No, "awfully slow" would be FTP'ing each result to a file server then concatenating the files remotely.  This is _slightly_ slower that using `StringBuilder`, granted, but _awfully_ slow is a bit of a stretch in my (biased) opinion.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: you are very correct. And I +1'd this answer because it's quite correct and concise.

Answer (score 0):

```
var strs = new string[100];
...

var result = strs.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(strs.Sum(x => x.Length)),
                            (sb, curr) => sb.Append(s + ", ")).ToString();
```

Just need to remove the last ", " from the end now.

Comment: Giving the `StringBuilder` a size yields a speedup, but not an asymptotic speedup. This may be less than the overhead from the `Sum`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string myString = "Hello World"
var myList= new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    myList.Add(i);

var newList = myList.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, num) => current + myString.Substring(num, 1));
```